# Extracting information from AJAX based sites using Python

Tags: python, ajax, data-mining

I am trying to retrieve query results on sites based on ajax like www.snapbird.org using Python. Since it doesn't show in the page source, I am not sure how to proceed.
I am a Python newbie and hence it would be great if I could get a pointer in the right direction. 
I am also open to some other approach to the task if that is easier

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be complex but as a start, ppen [firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28web_development%29) and find the URL that gets called when the AJAX request is handled. You can call that directly in your Python program and parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium's [Python client driver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to parse the page source. I usually use this in conjunction with [PyQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) to make web scraping easier.

Here's the [basic tutorial for Selenium's Python driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings). Be sure to follow the instructions for Selenium version **2** instead of version 1 (unless you're using version 1 for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

You could also configure chrome/firefox to an HTTP proxy and then log/extract the necessary content with the proxy.  I've tinkered with python proxies to save/log the requests/content based on content-type or URI globs.

For other projects I've written site-specific javascript bookmarklets which poll for new data and then POST it to my server (by dynamically creating both a form and iframe, and setting `myform.target=myiframe;`

Other javascript scripts/bookmarklets simulate a user interacting with sites, so instead of polling every few seconds the javascript automates clicking buttons and form submissions, etc.  These scripts are always very site-specific of course but they've been hugely useful for me, especially when iterating over all the paginated results for a given search.

Here is a stripped down version of walking over a list of "paginated" results and preparing to send the data off to my server (which then further parses it with BeautifulSoup).  In particular this was designed for Youtube's Sent/Inbox messages.

```
var tables = [];
function process_and_repeat(){
    if(!(inbox && inbox.message_pane_ && inbox.message_pane_.innerHTML)){
        alert("We've got no data!");
    }
    if(inbox.message_pane_.innerHTML.indexOf('<table') === 0)
    {
        tables.push(inbox.message_pane_.innerHTML);
        inbox.next_page();
        setTimeout("process_and_repeat()",3000);
    }
    else{
        alert("Fininshed, [" + tables.length + " processed]");
        document.write('<form action=http://curl.sente.cc method=POST><textarea name=sent.html>'+escape(tables.join('\n'))+'</textarea><input type=submit></form>')
    }
}

process_and_repeat();  // now we wait and watch as all the paginated pages are viewed :)
```

This is a stripped down example without any fancy iframes/non-essentials which just add complexity.

Adding to what Liam said, Selenium is a great tool, too, which has aided in my various scraping needs.  I'd be more than happy to help you out with this if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution might be using a browser like [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). So you can browse site, follow links, make searches and nearly everything that you can do with a browser with user interface.

But for a very sepcific job, you may not even need a such library, you can use `urllib` and `urllib2` python libraries to make a connection and read response... You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see data structure of a search and response body. Then use `urllib` to make a request with relevant parameters...

With an example...

I made a search with `joyvalencia` and check the request url with firebug to see:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=joyvalencia&count=100&page=2&include_rts=true&callback=twitterlib1321017083330
```

So calling this url with `urllib2.urlopen()` will be the same with making the query on Snapbird. Response body is:

```
twitterlib1321017083330([{"id_str":"131548107799396357","place":null,"geo":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"coordinates":.......
```

When you use `urlopen()` and read the response, the upper string is what you get... Then you can use `json` library of python to read the data and parse it to a pythonic data structure...