# Deferred Downloading using Python Requests Library

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to fetch some information from Workflowy using Python Requests Library. Basically I am trying to programmatically get the content under this URL: https://workflowy.com/s/XCL9FCaH1b

The problem is Workflowy goes through a 'loading phase' before the actual content is displayed when I visit this website so I end up getting the content of 'loading' page when I get the request. Basically I need a way to defer getting the content so I can bypass the loading phase.

It seemed like Requests library is talking about this problem here: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow but I couldn't get this example work for my purposes.

Here is the super simple block of code that ends up getting the 'loading page':

`import requests
    path = "https://workflowy.com/s/XCL9FCaH1b"
    r = requests.get(path, stream=True)
    print(r.content)`

Note that I don't have to use Requests just picked it up because it looked like it might offer a solution to my problem. Also currently using Python 2.7.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You can't do this with `requests`.  You need something that knows how to interpret the Javascript used to render that page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then I think I will start looking into PhantomJS. Seems like it offers the functionality to render the page without actually using a browser.

Comment: The initial page load triggers an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request to https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=XCL9FCaH1b&client_version=14 - parsing the tree structure from that JSON response should be pretty easy, if that's what you're after.

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks for your answer. I was able to achieve what I want using PhantomJS since it allows for the Javascript in the page to be executed and render the actual content. From then on, I was able to use jquery to parse the results into a JSON file

Comment: @LukasGraf I am only now understanding what you meant by your suggestion. With an additional inspiration from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084707/extracting-information-from-ajax-based-sites-using-python  I was able to use firebug to see the request url and use it to get the JSON response. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @hibernationTheory you're welcome ;-) In your case you already seem to have the `share_id` (`XCL9FCaH1b`), but if not, it should be trivial to extract from the response to the first request. So that's why I thought I'd point it out, two requests using the `requests` module should do it, that's probably way less messy than using PhantomJS.